# What are the effects of the various Protectron Personality Modes?

Tags: fallout-4

When activating a protectron in Fallout 4 you get the chance to choose its Personality Mode. The available modes are:

[image: Protectron Modes]

- Default
- Subway Steward
- Law Enforcement
- Fire Brigadier
- Medical Responder
- Construction Worker

**Do these modes serve any purpose ?** Is there any actual difference in the protectron behavior ?

Answer (score 27):

The different Protectron Modes exhibit demonstrably different behavior and combat capabilities.

**Construction Worker Mode** enforces workplace safety laws with deadly force. Specifically, it will attack anyone not wearing a *hard hat* (though it seems several other types of helms will also qualify).

**Law Enforcement Mode** will not attack you if you don't have a weapon drawn.

**Medical Responder Mode** does not appear to be hostile unless attacked, and when engaged in combat, will melee with it's "defibrillating" shock hands.

Comment: Not sure about the others at this time. Will need to do some more experimenting.

Comment: I haven't been attacked by protectrons in law enforcement mode at all, excluding cases in which I attacked them first.  Which ones did you experiment with?

Comment: I've been testing with the one at the Wicked Shipping depot.

Comment: Interesting.  I can't replicate that behavior with the protectron at the Super Duper Mart.  I'll have to take a look at that one.

Comment: I could be wrong on what exactly is triggering the law enforcement. The only one I'm 100% certain about right now is construction, but I'm experimenting.

Comment: In my experience the law enforcement one seems to turn hostile when it detects an attack from me

Comment: I'm unable to get consistent results, but the protectron at Wicked Shipping definitely seems to behave differently between modes.  I'm going to delete my answer for now, as it's clearly incorrect in this case.

Comment: After the subway one failed to not attack me even though I had a ticket, I stopped bothering with the personalities and leave it on default. They all seem to wait until I attack something before attacking me.

Comment: I've had a number of construction bots not attack me despite my lack of a hard hat. Are they not in construction worker mode by default?

Answer (score 9):

Well the Medical Responder does not attack you unless you attack it. The Subway Steward *should* take a token if you have it in your inventory like previous games (just a guess) as a way to get it to attack your enemies for you; but, as of right now, it will ask for a token, but attack anyway with the respons "delinquit actions will not be tolerated." even if it takes the token (which has happened to me). The rest just change dialogue, but will attack on sight.

---

The subway steward *WILL* accept a token but you have to hit the action key immediately when asked for the token... testing has shown the time permitted is less than a second.

Comment: They don't attack on sight, at least not on Normal.  I've activated three of them so far, after setting them to `Law Enforcement` mode.  They've all clearly seen me, never attacked me.   I also activated an attack bot.  No ill effects from that yet, but I still think it may not have been the idea, but it should be *fun*.

Comment: I have had a few of them attack me on sight, others just seem to attack enemies. Others didn't attack me at first but then attacked me. I just save before letting them out now.

Comment: @CoqPwner They attack you if you shoot at something. If you keep your gun put away, you can draw enemies toward them and they shoot the enemies.

Comment: I am in the 35 Court building now, and I have no idea how these things are working and how I can get one to work "for" me.  I have put away my weapon, sent Piper back to Sanctuary, and tried all the modes.  as soon as I activate it and it sees me, it attacks.  Every time.

Answer (score 5):

Fire Brigadier will tell you the object you are carrying is fire hazardous and to please dispose of it if you are carrying a weapon