# How can I avoid being killed by Subway Stewards/Ticket Inspectors?

Tags: fallout-4

Whenever I power up the Protectrons in the College Square Station subway (in 'Subway Steward' mode), they ask me for my token. If I attempt to show them my subway tokens however, they immediately try and kill me..

I have tried

- Interacting with them ('Talk' action)
- Dropping a Subway Token and dangling it in front of them (still had some in my bag as well)
- Standing still and not doing anything (this is what worked in Fallout 3, they would take a ticket/employee ID/other important McGuffin etc off you after a few seconds)

Every action ends up with them attacking me for my 'delinquent behaviour', apparently blaming me for the detritus, graffiti and dead bodies lying everywhere.

How can I safely activate Subway Protectrons?

Comment: This seems to be bugged at the moment. Hopefully a patch will fix it.

Comment: @DCShannon - really? that's a bugger :/

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242989/108003

Answer (score 10):

The way it's suppose to work is once they are activated with that personality, it does an inventory check for the "Subway Token". If you have one, it will take the token out of your inventory, then attack everything else in site but spare you.

I don't know whether it's a one time event, or would require more tokens upon revisiting the location later.

However, I've heard a lot about it being bugged at the moment and not working right. If that is the case, then a patch is set to be released this upcoming week. Hopefully that will be one of the fixes.

My recommendation for the robot is to set the personality to Law Enforcement, and keep your weapon holstered. Whenever enemies come out, run behind him. He will destroy whatever is around. If at any point he is destroyed, then step in and finish off the enemies. This way he never attacks you unless you draw your weapon, and it will save you ammo since he's killing off enemies.

When one is up against raiders they seem to be able to handle a few. If your lucky 5-10 at the most.

### Ghouls they seem to be handle around the same number. Different people may have different results.

I have new information based off of new experience, and research.

I found some information at the following links:

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Protectron_(Fallout_4)

I have tested this. You have to have a Subway Token in your inventory once the protectron is activated with this personality. Once the coin is requested, you have exactly 8 seconds to comply. In order to do this you need to press the action button immediately after he requests the coin, within 8 seconds.

You can pick pocket the coin back from him, but the next time he see's you, he will request it again. This information can all be backed up by the above URL, and a YouTube video showing this in action.

I have also verified this from personal experience within my own game as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will test when I get home and let you know :)

Comment: Of course. If you run into any issues, let me know and I will aid you in testing in my game, and further research.

Comment: Sorry for the ultra-late reply, but just got around to testing this again. Seems to be closer to 1 second, not 8 seconds, and I still have only successfully reproduced it once.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Protectron Override Program](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Protectron_override_program), found in [Wattz Consumer Electronics](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Wattz_Consumer_Electronics).

Most protectrons have a terminal associated with them. Most of these terminals can accept holotapes. If they can, then below the main screen you'll have the option to press X (on Xbox, same as the reload button) to load a holotape.

Once you load the Protectron Override Program, you can select Override Targeting Parameters. This will make the Protectron your ally. It will shoot your enemies, but not you. It is still necessary to activate the Protectron from the normal menu, if it's not already activated.

Answer (score -4):

Find a destraction or deactivate it

Comment: Please add more detail, as 10 word answers often aren't enough to solve a problem. Add for e.g. specifically explain how to distract, or how to deactivate.