# Why do Protectrons sometimes attack me?

Tags: fallout-4

Sometimes I activate the Protectron in Corvega Assembly plant, go to the side of the room and sneak as I watch it attack raiders. Then, all of a sudden, it would turn and start attacking me. Sure, sometimes I had tried to help it by firing a few shots, and maybe it saw that as being bad, but other times during the entire duration of it being active I don't use any weapons and just try to hide off to the side.

The strange part is it doesn't always happen, either. There are good odds it will not attack me unless I attack it first, but sometimes it seems to just decide it doesn't like me and attacks. Why is does it sometimes attack me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with the mode they're in:

[What are the effects of the various Protectron Personality Modes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242989/79975)

If they're in Construction or Law Enforcement mode, you can turn them hostile if you do not meet their requirements.

In Construction mode, you need to be wearing a Hard Hat.

In Law Enforcement mode, you cannot have a weapon drawn.

Answer (score 2):

As a continuation of Nelsons answer, there is also a Subway Attendant mode that you can put the protectron in. Once the protectron is in that mode, you can give him a subway token and he will no longer be hostile to you but will still attack any enemies.